# TIBCO BPM Pausing a process and resume later programmatically

Tags: java, tibco

I am currently developing in TIBCO BPM, I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically pause a specific process when it arrives at a certain stage.

and then later again programmatically resume the process. So the resume process will happen maybe via a webservice call.

Any advise is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use BPM API to pause/resume particular workflow by workflowId.

Check documentation about BPM API to find the exact service that you need.